# How to print the null values if the dictionary has it using LINQ

Tags: c#, dictionary, null, conditional-operator, null-coalescing

I have dictionary with the following keys and values. I am trying to print the dictionary, but nothing prints where there is a null value. How do I print "null" in the output?

```
Dictionary<string, object> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dic1.Add("id", 1);
            dic1.Add("name", "john");
            dic1.Add("grade", null);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dic1.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value}")));
```

Here is the output I get:

```
id: 1
name: john
grade:
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) (`??`) in this situation, which returns the value of its left-hand operand if it isn't `null`, otherwise it evaluates the right-hand operand and returns its result. So we only need to add `"null"` to the right hand side:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    dic1.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value ?? "null"}")));
```

**Output**

```
id: 1
name: john
grade: null
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a whirl.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dic1.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value ?? "null"}")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ternary conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator).

If the expression left of the `?` evaluates to `true`, the expression left of the `:` is evaluated. If `false`, the expression right of the `:` is evaluated.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dic1.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {(a.Value == null ? "null" : a.Value)}")));
```

The above is somewhat less elegant than the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) already mentioned.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dic1.Select(a => $"{a.Key}: {a.Value?? "null"}")));
```